# List of Tables - how to Colon(:) when list of table/figures

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

My paper's table in text looks like this:

[image]

However, I want the caption with colon behind Table 1 in text:

[image]

If I add the colon ":" in caption, my code is

```
\caption{:\textbf{ The Title}}
```

The List of Tables page will have two ":"

[image]

How to fix that? Also, I do not need "The title" bold in List of Tables Page, but it is better to bold in text.

Thank you very much! I will be very appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using a specific document class? If so, please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Please also tell us if your documents loads any packages that affect either the appearance of captions or the appearance of the table of contents and the list of tables.

Answer (score 1):

The standard classes (`book`, `report`, `article`, `memoir`, etc) print a caption in a table as (for the first table)

```
Table 1: Caption text
```

which is what you wanted. What have you done to prevent that?

You can use the `tocloft` package for changing the entry style in the LoT. Here's a MWE that provides what you are after.

```
% captiontocprob.tex  SE 545537
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table } % put this before the number
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{4em} % more space needed for Table number
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:} % put this after the table number
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}
  \centering
  A TABLE
  \caption{Tables's caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Read the `tocloft` documentation for detailed information (`texdoc tocloft`).

It would really have helpful if you had given us an MWE so we didn't have to guess what you had done; I'm doing my best to be nice but I'm a GOM.